# How to Copy Data from One sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the data from specific cells from one sheet to another sheet's specific cells.

This is the code I tried

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("KeyInformation").Select
Range("A2:Q2").Select
Range("A2:Q2").Copy

Sheets("Factsheet").Select
Range("B9:B25").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Factsheet").Select
End Sub
```

It copied. How can I paste where I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using select.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("KeyInformation")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Factsheet")
ws.Range("A2:Q2").Copy
ws1.Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws1.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool! It works.ONLY how i could activate the Sheet  Factsheet after coping data so it will be visible that info copied @Neelesh?

Comment: Perfect @Neelesh! One more question if i will want to copy just one cell like ws.Range("A2:Q2").Copy will this same code work?

Comment: What do you mean by one cell like only A2? if that so, then ws.range("A2").copy

Comment: Yes i mean like only A2

Answer (score 0):

if you want only to copy the row in the the new sheet in the same position, you have to declare the position where you want to paste the copied row:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("KeyInformation").Select
Range("A2:Q2").Select
Range("A2:Q2").Copy

Sheets("Factsheet").Select
' Find the last row of data
Range("A2:Q2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Factsheet").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to copy and paste it to specifc position. I tried your code but i got an error for this line Range("A2:Q2").Select . Any ideas @nicolò grando?

Comment: What is the error you see? I tested it on a blank workbook, added the named sheets and worked without issues here...

Comment: I just need to copy from sheet KeyInformation A2:Q2 to Factsheet B9:B25 @nicològrando

Comment: it cotinue to works on my excel. try to replace Range("B9:B25").Select with Sheets("Factsheet").Range("B9:B25").Select

Comment: I have already done but no luck. Does it make sense in which sheet the command button is @nicològrando? It is in KeyInformation

Comment: Do you have Hidden the second sheet , FactSheet?

Comment: No i guess. I just created that 2 sheets without changing anything @nicolò grando.

Comment: i upload my file on this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryzaq9l8c4eryea/Test.xlsm?dl=0)