# Fetching data from specified columns to a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with the subject of automated updating a report table with a separate source file, let me briefly explain the problem:

I have got a source file like on first screenshot below. I need to fetch **only** data in columns with headings highlighted in *red*.

[image]
[Sample of source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnPmE.png)

The next necessary condition is that in the result table (in a separate file), the records imported must be unique based on the first column (ID).

[image]
[Sample of result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIIr4.png)

How to write a proper macro which will check the IDs, skipping already existing and paste the records?
I started my code by opening a source file like below:

```
Sub Updater()
 Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
 Dim DestWbk As Workbook
 Dim Ws As Worksheet
 Dim Filename As String
 
    Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a Report File", MultiSelect:=False)
    
Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

SrcWbk.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: First step: [How to Copy Data from One sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647363/how-to-copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another/35647924)

Comment: There is an excel function to delete duplicates for a range. I cant remember the VB code, but you can record yourself doing it and then generalize the VB code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. You must provide the sheet names and header rows for the source worksheet and the destination worksheet. I've done so here with constants.

I first find the columns of the fields that need to be copied from the source worksheet using `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match`. I then loop through each ID in the source worksheet and check for a match in the destination worksheet. If no match is found, then the record is new and needs to be copied.

Then it's just a simple reference back to the source worksheet using the previously identified column numbers.

I save and close the destination workbook at the end, but you can remove or comment this as needed.

```
Sub Updater()
    
    ' Define source and destination sheets and header rows
    Const srcShtName = "Sheet1"
    Const destShtName = "Sheet1"
    Const srcHdrRow = 7
    Const destHdrRow = 1
    
    'Defing header range for source worksheet
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcShtName)
    Set hdrRng = srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(srcHdrRow, 1), srcWS.Cells(srcHdrRow, 1).End(xlToRight))
    
    ' Get all IDs from source worksheet
    srcIdCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("ID", hdrRng, 0)
    Set srcIDs = srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(srcHdrRow + 1, srcIdCol), srcWS.Cells(srcHdrRow + 1, srcIdCol).End(xlDown))

    ' Define fields to copy to destination worksheet and find corresponding column numbers
    fieldsToCopy = Array("Branch ID", "Product", "Shipment Category", "Port of Loading", "Year", "Month", "Day")
    ReDim srcColumns(0 To UBound(fieldsToCopy))
    fieldIdx = 0
    For Each field In fieldsToCopy
        srcColumns(fieldIdx) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(field, hdrRng, 0)
        fieldIdx = fieldIdx + 1
    Next field
    
    ' Open destination worksheet
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a Report File", MultiSelect:=False)
    Set destWS = Workbooks.Open(filename).Worksheets(destShtName)
    
    ' Define header range of destination worksheet
    Set destHdrRng = destWS.Range(destWS.Cells(destHdrRow, 1), destWS.Cells(destHdrRow, 1).End(xlToRight))
    destIdCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("ID", destHdrRng, 0)
    
    ' Loop through each record in source worksheet
    For Each ID In srcIDs

        ' Look for an ID in the destination worksheet that matches the current rcord
        destRow = Empty
        Set destIdRng = Intersect(destWS.Columns(destIdCol), destWS.UsedRange)
        On Error Resume Next
        destRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ID.Value, destIdRng, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If destRow is empty, the record was not found in the destination and we need to add it
        If destRow = Empty Then
            nextRow = destWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            For fieldIdx = 0 To UBound(srcColumns)
                destWS.Cells(nextRow, destIdCol).Value = ID.Value
                destWS.Cells(nextRow, fieldIdx + 2).Value = srcWS.Cells(ID.Row, srcColumns(fieldIdx)).Value
            Next fieldIdx
        End If
        
    Next ID
    
    ' Save the destination workbook and close it
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    destWS.Parent.Save
    destWS.Parent.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```